# Joomla and VirtueMart - Remove login button in checkout for guest

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I'm looking around, but I still have not found anything on the subject. I need to hide the login button when a guest makes purchases, the store is created with Joomla and Virtuemart latest versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the login button is a module, then assign that module to all pages except the checkout page.

If that doesn't work, then you will need to override the login module, and then have a condition in the overridden file to not display the button for guests who are on the checkout page. Here's [an answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9546/custom-component-need-to-verify-if-user-is-logged-in) for checking if a user is a guest.